# Error Response when Redirecting from IdentityServer3 using AngulrJs and Angular Ui Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, angular-ui-router, identityserver3

I'm creating a test app for working with IdentityServer 3 and i'm using AngularJs, Angular Ui Router and oauth-ng library for creating this. My app needs to work with OpenID connect Authorization Code Flow in the Client side. So i have made quite small changes to the oauth-ng library.

My test app successfully connects to the IdentityServer3 and gets the Authentication Code and the state. But when the server redirects to the redirect url i am getting a 404 error.The following message

[image]

But the URL has the authorization code and the state included in it. Here are some of the code i wrote.

**login.html - The View For Login**

```
<oauth
    site="https://localhost:44333/core"
    client-id="codeclient"
    response-type="code" // <= added this attribute
    redirect-uri="http://localhost:4443/redirect"
    scope="openid profile email">
</oauth>
```

The Redirect URL in the IdentityServer is properly configured. The following is the url returned by the IdentityServer3

> https://localhost:4443/redirect?code=5d5170f227fd2b90a8d87bdae0588baa&session_state=tWVYj9OnDPYzaN1GmDTsgmdXYMk2AfX5R8JsHEsWZ5Q.cfa44973eb00d05b306b6bc2e286c22e

But the above error happens. The Firefox browser gave an error on the Console stating the `Mixtype Error` suggesting i switch to HTTPS from HTTP. I also tried that with the following [python script](https://gist.github.com/dergachev/7028596) but that did not work either. Can some one please help.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the right authorize-path. check my settings

```
<oauth
site="https://localhost:44333"
client-id="angular-client-id"
redirect-uri="http://localhost:9000"
authorize-path="/connect/authorize"
response-type="id_token token"
nonce="value"
scope="openid profile {your resource scope}" style="width: 50%">
```